How to execute transactions from Root within a "fork locally" chain within Polkadot.js UI?
I'm trying to test XCM using Chopsticks but running into issues. One workaround I'm trying is to use Polkadot.js UI's "Fork Locally" option. I know several accounts are built in (Alice, Bob, etc) to use for testing, but I need to test with Root. How can I execute extrinsics from Root within a forked version within Polkadot.js UI?
(my specific issue - I want to deposit 5.4M ASTR into the HydraDX Omnipool. Hydra has scheduler pallet but only Root and Treasury accts can use it. Since this will be a big deposit, I might instead need to temporarily move the liquidity addition limits out of the way. So again, I'd like to test whether these calls will work if executed by a HydraDX referendum. Unfortunately, submitting the preimage fails because the HydraDX Treasury and the Astar sibling account don't hold the tokens yet. So I'm looking for a way to use Root to first set a large balance and then use Root to test executing the deposit of that large amount of tokens into the Omnipool.)
